# Where can I find wave height/period, current velocity and wind speed/direction data at the Qiangzhou strait in China?

Tags: wind, ocean-currents, waves, open-data

I'm looking for time series of wave height/ period, velocity currents and wind speed/direction specifically for the Qiangzhou strait in China.

Global data sets could also work.

Comment: Hi Gina, you are looking for past or current data?

Comment: I'm looking for historical data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve that information from [ERA5 reanalisys data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview). It cover the whole world from 1979 until almost the present. The resolution is 0.25°x0.25° and includes many fields that characterize ocean waves. here is a list of available fields for download in the "Ocean Waves" section:

[image]

And there is of course, winds data as well.

Comment: Dear Camilo, do you know a database where I could find current velocities?